# NDK use of undeclared identifier memcpy

Tags: android, android-ndk

My Android Studio got updated last friday and since then will refuse to compile my Android/NDK project, returning several errors about "use of undeclared identifier 'memcpy'" and "use of undeclared identifier 'memcmp'".

I've tried to do a clean install of Android Studio and all the Android SDK without any success. Several of my colleagues also had the update but can still compile.

Does anyone have any idea of what could be the problem ?

Comment: add `#include <cstring>` into it might be better

Comment: replace the string.h with cstring

Answer (score 19):

I have the same problem too. But under the Studio's CodeInsight

[image]

I just add the following code, the problem can be solved.

`#include <string.h>`